# Drools variable declaration in condition depending on class type using "not"

Tags: java, drools

I am processing messages extending a common base class in Drools, and for exactly one type I need to call a different getter for a variable definition in the rule condition. Both for the exception and all the other classes the value is *int* but the getter name is different. Otherwise the rule does exactly the same, that is why I am trying to solve it in one rule.

```
public class ClassBase {
    private int baseVal = 42;
    public int getBaseVal() {
        return baseVal;
    }
}

public class ClassA extends ClassBase {
    private int myVal = 42;
    public int getAval() {
        return myVal;
    }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassBase {
    private int myVal = 42;
    public int getBval() {
        return myVal;
    }
}

public class SomeClassWithInt {
    private int comp = 42;
    public int getComp() {
        return comp;
    }
}
```

My goal is to use the variable to find other facts and also use it in the consequence.

```
rule "different getter depending on class type"
when
    $base: ClassBase()
    ( ClassB( this == $base, $value: bval ) or
      not ClassB( this == $base, $value: baseVal ))
    $some: SomeClassWithInt( comp == $value )
then
    System.out.println($value);
end
```

Now if I add one *ClassA*, one *ClassB* and one *SomeClassWithInt* fact and call *fireAllRules()* this rule does not fire. If I replace the *not classB(...)* part with *ClassA(...)* it works like I want it to.

Can anybody tell me why the *not* version does not work?

Comment: Isn't "ClassB( this == $base, $value: bval ) or not ClassB( this == $base, $value: baseVal )" a tautology?

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what I want: the rule should fire for all `ClassBase` facts except that it sets one variable differently for `ClassB` and does it another way for all others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found the solution.

```
rule "Working"
when
    $base: ClassBase( )
    (ClassB( this == $base, $value : bval ) or
    ClassBase( this == $base, $cl : class, $cl != ClassB, $value : baseVal) )
then
    // Do something with $value
end
```

As stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825895/drools-variable-declaration-in-condition-depending-on-class-type-using-not#comment27777280_18825961) I tried this before but without the assignment to `$cl` which should not be necessary but my version(it is a customized version, not sure what version it is based on) of Drools seems to have a bug and the version `class != ClassB` just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the condition `not ClassB(this == $base, $value:baseVal)` being satisfied means that `$value` remains *unbound*. Therefore Drools properly refuses to allow you to use this variable.

Comment: I think my understanding of `not` is incorrect. I thought using `not` this way would make the rule fire for all facts not being `ClassB` instances and assign the `$value` variable the return value of `getBaseVal()`. 
`rule "Other"
 when
     $base: ClassBase()
     not ClassA( this == $base, $hash : hashCode )
 then
     System.out.println($hash);
end`
Drools does not complain about a syntax error, the rule does not fire.

Comment: `not` means "there is no instance in the knowledge which satisfies these constraints", so it shouldn't be bound to any specific object.

Comment: I see your point, I have another question than: if I remove the `$value: bval` part, the rule would fire also for `ClassA` facts as they satisfy the `not ClassB(...)`. I know that it is not going to work since `$value` cannot be resolved in that case and that is exactly what I am missing. If the `not ClassB()` is true I want to set `$value` to `$base.getBaseVal()`. Do You know how to do it?

Comment: Basically, you want to exclude one of base class's subclasses from matching? Would a negated `instanceof` condition work? Then you could have everything in your first constraint (the `instanceof` condition, and the `baseVal` binding).

Comment: Yes, I want to do exactly that. Your suggestion sounds good, but I don't know how to use `instanceof` in the constraint. I tried, but can't figure out the right syntax. Can You maybe post a code example?

Comment: I'm suggesting this from the top of my head. I don't have a Drools environment currentyl set up. Sorry :)

Comment: Thanks @marko-topolnik for your time! I can't figure this one out. To add to my confusion I tried following simple rules `ClassBase( class == ClassB )` and `ClassBase( class != ClassB )`. Both compile and run without syntax or runtime errors and guess what: both fire for fact `ClassB`...